# Clean Column names of multiple DataFrames

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to clean the column names of multiple data frames, rather than simply doing it one it at a time currently. See code below.

```
#Create data frame with basic data
patientID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
AdmDate <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-10-11','2008-3-25','2016-4-23','2011-6-12'))
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2")
`p-status` <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(`patient ID`, `Adm Date`, diabetes, `p-status`)
patientdata

#Find and replace spaces in column names 
names(patientdata) <- str_replace_all(names(patientdata)," *",'')

#Find and replace hyphen in column name
names(patientdata) <- str_replace_all(names(patientdata),"-",'')

names(patientdata)
```

I need to do these same procedures(replace spaces/periods in column names, and hyphens) on at least two different data frames, but I can't supply a vector of col names to str_replace_all. The normal way of doing this would require at least 3 different str_replace all statements for every data frame. Also, the dataframe's that I am working with are named differently(like order_table and sales_table). Thoughts on how to do this with less lines of code?

Comment: The column names do not match in the example

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example step-by-step process:

```
#Create data frame with basic data
`patient ID` <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
`Adm Date` <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-10-11','2008-3-25','2016-4-23','2011-6-12'))
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2")
`p-status` <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(`patient ID`, `Adm Date`, diabetes, `p-status`, check.names=FALSE)

#Create copies
patientdata2 <- patientdata3 <- patientdata4 <- patientdata

#Make list with all data frames
lst <- mget(ls(pattern="^patientdata"))

#Create Single Function to house all operations

nameChange <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- str_replace_all(names(df)," *",'')
  names(df) <- str_replace_all(names(df),"-",'')
  return(df)
}

#Iterate over all data frames
library(stringr)
lapply(lst, nameChange)
# $patientdata
#   patientID    AdmDate diabetes   pstatus
# 1         1 2010-10-11    Type1      Poor
# 2         2 2008-03-25    Type2  Improved
# 3         3 2016-04-23    Type1 Excellent
# 4         4 2011-06-12    Type2      Poor
# 
# $patientdata2
#   patientID    AdmDate diabetes   pstatus
# 1         1 2010-10-11    Type1      Poor
# 2         2 2008-03-25    Type2  Improved
# 3         3 2016-04-23    Type1 Excellent
# 4         4 2011-06-12    Type2      Poor
# 
# $patientdata3
#   patientID    AdmDate diabetes   pstatus
# 1         1 2010-10-11    Type1      Poor
# 2         2 2008-03-25    Type2  Improved
# 3         3 2016-04-23    Type1 Excellent
# 4         4 2011-06-12    Type2      Poor
```

We can also avoid list creation, if that is preferred:

```
patientdata <- nameChange(patientdata)
patientdata2 <- nameChange(patientdata2)
patientdata3 <- nameChange(patientdata3)
```

Comment: This function `nameChange` will return a new data.frame, unlike the solutions provided by @akrun and me which merely edit the names attribute of the existing data.frame.  That could make this answer expensive on large lists of large data.frames.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 both of akrun's answers return data frames

Comment: Also this answer can be generalized to concepts of applying functions to multiple data frames with one call. `data.table` speedy code is helpful, but does not teach OP how to think in terms of multiple data frame functional applications. Both answers provide value.

Comment: true on both points, I forgot that setNames (not data.table::setnames) returns the object...

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas. I don't have a whole lot of experience with functional programming, so this approach really helps. I think being able to house the operations in a functions and call it with lapply really simplifies things. What are your thoughts on using mutate_each or mutate_if as a way to apply the regular expression? I was using it earlier today for converting POSIXct types to Date, and was unsure if it could be used in this situation.

Comment: It won't help bc it is operating inside the data frame on the rows and columns. But what you are trying is on the outer column names. Very different

Comment: I see. I think one thing I should have clarified on the question is that each of my data frames are named different, like patient_data, and clinic_data. How would I be able to put them in a list to then use lapply to make the changes to all of them at once? Or is that even possible?

Comment: Yes just "my list = list(patientdata, clinicdata, otherdata)"

Comment: Hmm I tried running your code, and it doesen't seem to work...did you mean this:mydfs = c(order_table, return_table)
lapply(mydfs, nameChange)? That seems to iterate over the entire dataframe...

Comment: I did not use the c function that you used. Check the code again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120366/discussion-between-petergensler-and-pierre-lafortune).

Answer (score 3):

Using `setnames` from `data.table` is super convenient.

Also, your regexes seems simple enough that you can combine them into one such as `( *|-)`

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1=c(1,2,3),b2 = c(4,5,6), c3 = c(7,8,9))
df2 <- copy(df1)
df3 <- copy(df1)

library(data.table)
for (df_name in c("df1","df2","df3")){
    setnames(get(df_name), gsub("a|b|c","whatever",colnames(get(df_name))))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mgsub` from `qdap` after placing the datasets in a `list`

```
library(qdap)
lst <- mget(ls(pattern="^patientdata"))
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) setNames(x, mgsub(c(" ", "-"), c("", ""), names(x))))
```

Or we can just use `gsub`

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) setNames(x, gsub("[- ]+", "", names(x))))
names(lst1[[1]])
#[1] "patientID" "AdmDate"   "diabetes"  "pstatus"
```

Comment: interesting, I learned a new function from this, +1.. my only comment is that the OP wasn't asking for a list of data.frames, just to clean the data.frames.  So I thought editing them in place made more sense.  If you want to use `lapply`, one option would be to use `ls(pattern=...)` to return a list of data.frame names, not the data.frames themselves.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  I understand it, but it may be better to place them in a `list` if the OP wanted to do more changes subsequently.